# Suppressing = on a line in the align environment

Tags: align

How do I produce the following in `align` environment?

```
\begin{eqnarray*}& & abcd \\
&=& defg\\
&=& hijk
\end{eqnarray*}
```

I try

```
\begin{align*}&  abcd \\
&= defg\\
&= hijk
\end{align*}
```

But the result is not what I wanted.

Comment: See also: [How to align a set of multiline equations - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44450/how-to-align-a-set-of-multiline-equations?rq=1) & some note about mathrel: [spacing - How to align displayed, multi-line computations - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/580897/how-to-align-displayed-multi-line-computations)

Answer (score 17):

To avoid guessing about the space, you can use

```
\begin{align*}
  &\mathrel{\phantom{=}} abcd \\
  &= defg\\
  &= hijk
\end{align*}
```

Comment: That is the cleanest version.

Comment: It can get much cleaner if you define `\newcommand*{\pheq}{\hphantom{{}={}}}` (or with `\mathrel` but with `h`).

Answer (score 11):

Here you've got the fifth solution, which shows you that what you want to do is indeed slightly tricky in `align`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
     & abcd \\
 ={} & defg \\
 ={} & hijk 
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

The trick: If you have the `=` in the left column, then you need to put something after it to get correct spacing.

Answer (score 5):

This is sort of cheating, but in your example document, the following also works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

 \begin{align*}
    a&bcd \\
  = d&efg \\
  = h&ijk
 \end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Why?  Because I know that a, d, and h all have the same width.  This trick is surprisingly generalizable.

Another solution gives virtually identical results as `eqnarray`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

 \begin{equation*}
  \begin{aligned}
   & & abcd \\
   &=& defg \\
   &=& hijk
  \end{aligned}
 \end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

This works because the `aligned` subenvironment (which must be enclosed in a larger `equation` or the like) shrinks to fit its contents exactly, and separates columns by a minimal amount.  You can tweak this amount by redefining `\minalignsep`:

```
\renewcommand*{\minalignsep}{2em} % 10pt by default
```

as in this answer: [Could I change the default column sep of `aligned` from \quad to \qquad globally?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13346/could-i-change-the-default-column-sep-of-aligned-from-quad-to-qquad-globally/13356#13356).

Personally, I would go with Hendrik Vogt's method, though.

Answer (score 4):

```
\begin{align*}
  &\quad\, abcd \\
  &=       defg \\
  &=       hijk
\end{align*}
```

Comment: I find that \quad\ abcd\\ is better than \quad\,abcd\\

Answer (score 4):

in this special case you can use the order `=&`, which should be by default the other way round:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  &\; abcd \\
 =&\; defg\\
 =&\; hijk 
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

A quick and dirty solution would be

```
\begin{align*}&abcd \\
=\ &defg\\
=\ &hijk
\end{align*}
```

Obviously, you can increase the whitespace as you might wish.