# Could I change the default column sep of `aligned` from \quad to \qquad globally?

Tags: spacing, equations

I need your help: to change the default column sep of `aligned` from `\quad` to `\qquad` globally, thanks.

Comment: An alternate route might be to use the `alignedat` environment, which allows you to choose the spacing between aligned elements.  That is, the default spacing is zero, so the final spacing equals whatever space you choose to insert.

Comment: give an example of what you really mean. `aligned` didn't use a `\quad`

Comment: @ Herbert: My mistake. I had thought the space as a quad. So, I want a way to change the sep globally whatever it is a quad or not. @ Phil Hirschhorn: I've finish the draft, hard work to replace all aligned to alignedat, even alignedat is easy to customize.

Answer (score 4):

You could modify the value of `\minalignsep`:

```
\renewcommand*{\minalignsep}{2em}
```

It is `10pt` by default. If you write this into your preamble, after loading amsmath, the change is globally, as desired. However, it's also valid for other align environments. That may be desired as well, to preserve consistent math environments.

By this redefinition you can keep the modification of `\minalignsep` local to `aligned`:

```
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{aligned}{%
  \renewcommand*{\minalignsep}{2em}
  \let\@testopt\alignsafe@testopt
  \aligned@a
}{%
  \crcr\egroup
  \restorecolumn@
  \egroup
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: @ Stefan Kottwitz: Many thanks. Would you tell me which does "other align environments" mean? Include the "align" and "alignat" and "flalign" and the forth? Unless the align environment col sep will not increases, or it is not I want.

Comment: @never shown: `align` and `align*` also use the same space between columns like `aligned`, which is meaningful. Do you also use several columns with `align` and wish to keep the space narrow, in contrast to `aligned`? If yes, `aligned` itself could be redefined or an internal macro could be changed, the first would be the better choice.

Comment: You said right. I wrote some multiple lines structure with "align" but not "aligned" because "align" could be broken by page. If their col sep increases, I have to took much time to check the horizontal overflow boxs. But how to redifine the "aligned"?

Comment: @never shown: I added an example redefinition of `aligned`.

Comment: That's so good! Ever so much greatful!