# Slight misalignment using hphantom equals sign in align

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, align, relation-symbols

I am attempting to align the integral signs precisely, whilst still retaining the correct spacing around the equals signs. Why doesn't the following code get it exactly right?

```
\begin{align}
    & \hphantom{{}={}} \int \\
    & = \int \\
    & = F
\end{align}
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Suppressing = on a line in the align environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10408/suppressing-on-a-line-in-the-align-environment)

Comment: I asked this question 7 years ago, but it does not appear to be the same as the one linked.

Comment: Default flag-generated comment for possible duplicate flag. The one with close/reopen voting privilege are the one making the decision, not me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An alternative approach would be to set the spacing based on the fact that `=` is a relation. Therefore, use `\mathrel{\phantom{=}}` (`\hphantom` is not really needed):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
   a & \mathrel{\hphantom{=}} \int \\
   b & = \int \\
   c & = F
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems like a good option. I thought that `\hphantom{{}={}}` should effectively be telling LaTeX the same information as `\mathrel`, but I guess not.

Answer (score 12):

Let's start with an analysis of math atoms and spacings between them:

```
& = \int
```

The `align` environment adds an invisible empty subformula `{}` at the start of the column:

```
{} = \int
```

A subformula is acts as `\mathord`. The following line shows the math atoms with their type in the subscript position:

`{}`<sub>ord</sub> `=`<sub>rel</sub> `\int`<sub>op</sub>

There is a table in "The TeXbook" from Donald E. Knuth or in section "23.6.1 Classification of `mu` glue" in book ["TeX by Topic"](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/texbytopic/TeXbyTopic.pdf) from Victor Eijkhout, which shows the spacing between math atoms.
The spacing information is put in the superscript position between the math atoms:

`{}`<sub>ord</sub> <sup>thick</sup> `=`<sub>rel</sub> <sup>thick</sup> `\int`<sub>op</sub> <sup>thin</sup> `\int`<sub>op</sub>

The same analysis for

```
& \hphantom{{}={}} \int
```

yields:

`{}`<sub>ord</sub> <sup>none</sup>
`{` `{}`<sub>ord</sub> <sup>thick</sup> `=`<sub>rel</sub> <sup>thick</sup>
`{}`<sub>ord</sub> `}`<sub>ord</sub>
<sup>thin</sup> `\int`<sub>op</sub>

The `\hphantom{...}` acts as subformula.
As can be seen, there is an additional thin space (`\thinmuskip`) between `\hphantom{...}` and the following operator.

This space can be canceled by `\!`:

```
& \hphantom{{}={}} \! \int
```

Macro `\!` negates the thin space, it is defined in LaTeX as:

```
\def\!{\mskip-\thinmuskip}
```

An alternative is to remove the empty subformulas in `\hphantom` and convert the `\hphantom` to a rel atom as a visible `=` would have been:

```
& \mathrel{\hphantom{=}} \int
```

Analysis:

`{}`<sub>ord</sub> <sup>thick</sup>
`{` `=`<sub>rel</sub> `}`rel
<sup>thick</sup> `\int`op

Example file with increased `\thinmuskip` to show the spacing problem more clearly:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\thinmuskip=40mu

\begin{align}
 \texttt{\detokenize{& = \int}}\colon
 & = \int \\
 \texttt{\detokenize{& \hphantom{{}={}} \int}}\colon
 & \hphantom{{}={}} \int \\
 \texttt{\detokenize{& \hphantom{{}={}} \! \int}}\colon
 & \hphantom{{}={}} \! \int \\
 \texttt{\detokenize{& \mathrel{\hphantom{=}} \int}}\colon
 & \mathrel{\hphantom{=}} \int
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]