# How to align displayed, multi-line computations

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, align, line-breaking

I work in a field of mathematics where long, multi-line computations are bread and butter, and I mostly use `align*` (and its siblings) from the `amsmath` package to display them. However, I have not found a simple, foolproof way of typesetting such expressions. *What is the easiest way of correctly aligning lines horizontally in multi-line expressions?*

Ideally, the solution should not be overly technical, lest my coauthors resort to easier, but incorrect, solutions.

Take the following caricature of a multi-line computation: `x = -y [newline] -y`. If I have understood Knuth and Swanson[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONK9q.png) correctly, then the above should be typeset as

[image: Correctly aligned multi-line expression]

that is, something like

```
x [thickspace] = [thickspace] - [no space] y
                              - [medium space] y
```

(where the minuses are horizontally aligned). (There should be no space after the first minus, since it's a unary operator, and a medium space after the second, since it's a binary operator.)

I have searched StackExchange for solutions, but in vain. Below are the solutions I have found so far, with MWEs at the bottom.

[image: Some incorrect solutions]

1. The correct, but **overly complicated** way:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{amsmath}
   \begin{document}
   \begin{align*}
   x &= -y \\
   &\mathrel{\phantom{=}} -\:y
   \end{align*}
   \end{document}
   ```
2. Do nothing. **The minuses are incorrectly aligned.**

   ```
   x &= -y \\
   &-y
   ```

   (I'm only changing the contents of `align*` here.)
3. Indent arbitrarily using e.g. \quad or \qquad. **The minuses are incorrectly aligned.**

   ```
   x &= -y \\
   &\quad -y
   ```
4. Use \phantom. **The minuses are incorrectly aligned.**

   ```
   x &= -y \\
   &\phantom{=} -y
   ```
5. Use \mathrel{\phantom}. **The minuses are incorrectly aligned, and there is no medium space after the second minus.**

   ```
   x &= -y \\
   &\mathrel{\phantom{=}} -y
   ```
6. Use {}&. **There seems to be a thin and a thick space after the equals sign, and a thin space after the first minus.**

   ```
   x ={}& -y \\
   & -y
   ```
7. Use aligned. **Produces the same as in (6).**

   ```
   x &= \begin{aligned}[t]
   &-y \\ &-y
   \end{aligned}
   ```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONK9q.png): Donald Knuth: *The TeXbook*, page 170 and [Ellen Swanson: *Mathematics into Type*](https://www.ams.org/publications/authors/mit-2.pdf), Section 3.3.5.

*Edit 29 January: I misread Knuth's table; there should be a medspace after the second minus. Also, turned the fragments into a full document.*

Comment: What about `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
x = &-y \\
&-y
\end{align*}
\end{document}`?

Comment: @leandriis that  gives mathbin spacing for -

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Interesting, didn't know that.

Comment: 1 puts a thin space between - and y which is not the space you would normally get for an infix binary - (which is medspace) 3 is what I would do (or better  qquad)  (It is _always_ better to post a complete document not fragments)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Thanks, I changed "thin space" to "medspace" and turned to fragment into a full document. Regarding qquad, see my comment to your answer.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}


\begin{align*}
  x ={}& {-}y \\
   & {-}\:y
\end{align*}



\end{document}
```

This produces the spacing that you ask for as clarified in comments:

`x={}` gives standard thickmuspace around =

`{-}y` then forces the prefix - with no space added,

and `{-}\:` produces a medmuspace between - and y as you would get automatically in `x-y`

---

The above however is not the layout I would use as there is no real semantic reason to align the - and (as can better be seen with a more typical alignment involving a second = or inequality) it makes it harder to distinguish a wrapped continuation line from a second aligned equation.

Compare the first form using the spacing given above with the second which has much simpler markup and I would say much clearer layout.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}


\begin{align*}
  x ={}& {-}y \\
   & {-}\:y \\
   ={}&{-}2y
\end{align*}


\begin{align*}
  x &= -y \\
   &  \qquad - y \\
   & =-2y
\end{align*}



\end{document}
```

Comment: This is equivalent to "solution" 5. It's incorrect because the second minus is typeset as a unary instead of binary operator.

Comment: @Ulrik OK done as you ask (although I would never use this layout) I'd be more likely to add `\qquad` at the start of the second line to indent it as it is a continuation not a second aligned equation.

Comment: @Ulrik see updated answer with enlarged example.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, but I feel all three solutions suffer from the faults mentioned in my question: The second solution is overly complicated (I would have a hard time convincing my coathors to write this themselves), and the third solution arbitrarily and incorrectly indents the continued line.

**Note:** I consider [Ellen Swanson](https://www.ams.org/publications/authors/mit-2.pdf) the authority in these matters, and Section 3.5.5b clearly states "… align to the right of the first verb" (= in this example). See also 3.5.5d: "always keep expression visually within fences".

Comment: You are asking for a layout not directly supported and I show it with three extra `{` groups and a `\:`  which seems pretty minimal, or you could as wipet just showed use a negative space and a custom command to have less markup in each instance. Either way it is _not_ doing what ES states of aligning on the = the reason you are needing extra markup is that you are aligning on an unusual asymmetrically spaced - with no space to the left and a medium space to the right, and such a symbol spacing is not directly supported in tex. @Ulrik

Comment: Please see the figure in Swanson's Section 3.3.5b. She's *not* saying you should align at the =, but *to the right* of the =. I honestly don't understand what is "unusual" about this example – the first minus is a negation operator, and the second minus is a binary operator. Swanson clearly says they should be aligned. How can this not be supported in TeX?

Comment: @Ulrik Swanson 3.3.5b is a vague sketch you are choosing to interpret that as saying that the `-` on the wrapped line should be asymmetrically spaced, I don't see any reason to interpret it that way. But as I say I would definitely indent this, especially if there are following forms that _do_ need to align on the = as I show above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119077/discussion-between-ulrik-and-david-carlisle).

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
\def\n{\mathrel{\phantom{=}}\mskip-\thinmuskip{}}

$$\eqalign{
  x &= -y \cr
    &\n -y
}
$$
\bye
```

Comment: +1 yes I wondered about suggesting something like that as well, you are probably right that as this puts all the extra markup in one place it's easier to define a custom command to do it. (I still wouldn't use this layout though as I think it's confusing for the reader)

Comment: Thanks, this seems like a robust solution. I was hoping to avoid having to create new macros, though – since this must be a very commonly encountered issue, I felt it should be natively supported by TeX (or LaTeX, or amsmath).