# align when there is no equals on the first line

Tags: align

Consider the following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    &abcde \\
    &= vwxyz
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

This produces

[image]

I would like to align the start of the top line (the 'a') with the start of the expression on the bottom line (the 'v').

I tried moving the alignment character after the '=', but it messes up the spacing around the equals sign:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    &abcde \\
    =& vwxyz
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I also tried using a phantom '=', but it only seems to account for the width of the equals sign itself, not the spacing around it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    &\phantom{=} abcde \\
    &= vwxyz
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

What is the correct way to achieve this?

Comment: Almost the same as [spacing - How to align displayed, multi-line computations - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/580897/how-to-align-displayed-multi-line-computations)

Comment: On examining the linked question, it is asking for something slightly more complicated and has more complicated answers as a result - I don't think it's the same.

Comment: At the moment I don't see, whether or not the 5 or 6 answers, David proposes in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10408/suppressing-on-a-line-in-the-align-environment, did or did not help.

Comment: @MS-SPO I think if you compare them to Mico's answer below you will see that they are all more complicated. This is because they are answers to a different question. If a future user has the same question as me, they are more likely to be helped by the answers below, which are answers to my question, than by answers to the linked question, which are answers to a different question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, the typical answer at SE is "how to do it" but not "why". I try to fill the gap.

The LaTeX align environment works (rougly speaking) like

```
\halign{\hfil$\displaystyle{#}$&$\displaystyle{{}#}$\hfil\cr ...data&data... \cr}
```

It means that the first column is set by `$\displaystyle{data}$` but the second one by `$\displaystyle{{}data}$`. The emtpy group `{}` here creates an empty math atom of Ord type. The idea is copied from Plain TeX macros.

If `data` in the second column is `=abc` then the result is `{{}=abc}`. The equal sign creates an atom of Rel type. We see here Ord Rel Ord Ord Ord. The Ord-Rel pair gives `\thickmuskip` space between them and Rel-Ord gives the same space, so we have spacing around the equal sign.

If the `data` in the fist column is `=` then we have `{=}` and it creates the Ord atom with equal sign in the nucleus without spacing. But if the `data` is `={}` then we have `{={}}`, i.e. Rel-Ord which makes `\thickmuskip` space between Rel and Ord.

The spacing between math atoms are controlled using the table given at page 170 in TeXbook. You can see similar table in [this document](https://petr.olsak.net/ftp/olsak/optex/optex-math.pdf) at page 3.

Comment: Future readers might want to note: this great answer gives the 'why'; the 'how' is in Mico's answer below. (Basically just replace `=&` with `={}&` in my first code example.)

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to align the start of the top line (the `a`) with the start of the expression on the bottom line (the `v`). ... I tried moving the alignment character after the `=`, but it messes up the spacing around the equals sign.

Just change

```
     &abcde \\
    =& vwxyz
```

to either

```
     &abcde \\
  ={}& vwxyz
```

or

```
     &abcde \\
{}={}& vwxyz
```

---

A full MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
         &abcde \\
    {}={}& vwxyz
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Zarko - Yes, it is. I'll adjust the answer accordingly.

Comment: The `{}={}` version adds undesired space; `={}` is the one.